# tab autocomplete on python script execution in console

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, unix, execution

i'm having this "issue" (for lack of better word), whenever i run my python script with arguments, i can't use the tab completion function of Unix consoles. For example when i want to put a file in the script execution.
Hope this examples illustrate better my issue.

Case 1

```
>python3 script.py
 [tab]
 folder/ folder1/ data.dat
```

Case 2

```
>python3 script.py -f d
 [tab]
 folder/ folder1/ (file data.dat not showing)
```

Ideal case

```
>python3 script.py -f data.dat - n 2 ....
```

Hope i made myself clear, and someone can explain this to me, i'm guessing python won't allow this, or needs to be configured in someway.

I'm using `argparse` in my script with the usual code..

```
    ap.add_argument('-f', '--file', type=str, action='store', help='Input file.',metavar='FILE')
```

I've already tried with `type=argparse.FileType('r')` but is the same.

I want to achieve this because of the files i'm currently working have long names, and it was requested to not write the files names every time.

Anyway, thanks for reading.

Comment: It has absolutely nothing to do with python.  What shell/OS are you using?

Comment: Debian 8 wheezy or Ubuntu 16.04, it's the same on both, with the default's shells.

Comment: So bash, I'm guessing.  This works perfectly fine for me in bash, though I'm not using the same distro's as you.  It should filter based off the last letter you types, so if you type `-f d`, I wouldn't expect it to show `folder/` or `folder`/` since neither of those start with a `d`

Comment: yes, i know that, i expect that if i type `-f d` the file `data.dat` would show. but it doesn't @BrendanAbel

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for a work around this. Using python 3.5 i can achieve what i wanted, autocomplete name of files in bash when executing a python script.

so with

```
> python3 script.py
[tab]
 folder/ folder1/ data.dat
> python3 script.py -f d
[tab]
folder/ folder1/ (file data.dat not showing)
```

and with python 3.5

```
> python3.5 script.py -f d
[tab]
 folder/ folder1/ data.dat
```

this pages lead me to some valueable answers too.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interactive.html

https://argcomplete.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Thanks again.